# I have a pandas table as displayed. How can i remove the index and other data from repeating?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
Index   Testresult      Testtime(secs)                 Testname
0       PASS            0.034165            This will Display a
0       PASS            0.034165      Dictionary in the console
0       PASS            0.034165         and also write to file
1       PASS            0.00491                     Display Sum
2       PASS            0.004247              Display Factorial
```

I want it this way:

```
Index   Testresult      Testtime(secs)                 Testname
0       PASS            0.034165            This will Display a
                                      Dictionary in the console
                                         and also write to file

1       PASS            0.00491                     Display Sum

2       PASS            0.004247              Display Factorial
```

Meaning, the Test result and Test time shall be printed only on the first row if there are multiple rows of text.

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow. Please try to make your example reproducible. Idealy some lines of pandas code to create your DataFrame, how you display it so far with output and a DataFrame with the desired output. As it stands I do not understand your question ;)

Comment: You need to provide a minimal code that they can reproduce the problem. See more details on how to post a question at this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Index, Testresult and Testtime as levels of a Multiindex, you get pandas will sparsify that for you

```
In [30]: df.set_index(['Index', 'Testresult', 'Testtime(secs)'])                                                                                                                                  
Out[30]: 
                                                            Testname
Index    Testresult       Testtime(secs)                            
0        PASS       0.0342                            This will...  
                    0.0342                      Dictionary in t...  
                    0.0342                         and also wri...  
1        PASS       0.0049                                    D...  
2        PASS       0.0042                              Display...
```

However, leaving out everything that could index your data (that means testtime as well) is really difficult to do in pandas as it makes the whole idea of an index obsolete. If you really need it, you can always loop over the dataframe and compare to the last row

EDIT:
Something like that:

```
In [74]: last_index = [] 
    ...: for _, row in df.iterrows(): 
    ...:     current_index = row[['Index', 'Testresult', 'Testtime(secs)']].values.tolist() 
    ...:     if current_index != last_index: 
    ...:         print(*current_index, end='') 
    ...:     print(row['Testname']) 
    ...:     last_index = current_index 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                   
0    PASS       0.034165            This will Display a
      Dictionary in the console
         and also write to file
1    PASS       0.00491                    Display Sum
2    PASS       0.004247              Display Factorial
```

There are some things like why exactly you need `.values.tolist()` and the `_` and `*` that you don't need to worry about (yet). Focus on understanding how the code compares the current index and the last one.

You will have to do the formatting with whitespaces and so on yourself ;)

Also, this is by no means the most elegant way to solve your problem in python. But probably the easiest to understand ;)

Comment: Thank you for this. Actually, I am not much familiar with pandas. Can you let me know how can the looping be done with an example? Or any other solution to display the table as above(not pandas, some other module)?

Comment: This is my current code:                          '''test_items_list = [[['This will Display a Dictionary',' in the console and also',' write to file'], 'PASS', '0.034165'], ['Display Sum', 'PASS', '0.00491'], ['Display Factorial', 'PASS', '0.004247']]
data = pd.DataFrame(test_items_list,
    columns = ['Testname' , 'Testresult', 'Testtime(secs)'],
    index = [1,2,3])
s = data.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['Testname']),axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
s.name = 'Testname'
print(s)
df = data.drop('Testname', axis=1).join(s)
print(df)'''

Comment: That is not fixing this issue. I am not getting the output as you have shown.

Comment: texttable is a much better option for tabulating data. It provides flexible alignment and is easy to understand. Got this worked!